# Autoloading custom Zend_Form_Element

Tags: php, zend-framework, bootloader, zend-form-element

I can't get Zend to autoload a custom form element class. I did things exactly as Marcin describes [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124561/how-to-render-some-html-in-zend-form) (except that my classes start with 'Zend' and not 'my' but I'm getting this error:

`Warning: include_once(Zend\Form\Element\Div.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I have `Zend_Form_Element_Div` inside `forms\elements\` and `Zend_View_Helper_FormDiv` inside `views\helpers\`

Basically, every folder in the error message is missng an 's', the right path is `Zend\Forms\Elements\Div.php`

I also have this in my bootstrap, though I'm not sure if it's necessary, but I'm also using this for my forms and models folder (and some others, but I don't think there's need to post them all):

```
<?php
    $resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(array(
        'model' => array(
        'namespace' => 'Model',
        'path' => 'models'
        ),
        'element' => array(
        'namespace' => 'Element',
        'path' => 'elements'
        ),
        'form' => array(
        'namespace' => 'Form',
        'path' => 'forms'
        )
));
?>
```

(Is there actually any other way of doing this autoloading? Instead of declaring every single folder?)

### Update:

- Element_Div in application/forms/elements/Div.php
- In my forms init() method: `$this->addElementPrefixPath('Element_', APPLICATION_PATH . '/forms/elements');`
- Error I'm getting: `Fatal error: Class 'Element_Div' not found in C:\xampplite\htdocs\code\application\forms\PostForm.php on line 63`

Comment: If you name your element Zend_Form_Element_Div, Zend autoloader will assume that it is is in library\Zend\Form\Element\ folder. Thus you get this error. So you could try putting it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially have to tell *the form* where to find custom elements by using:

`$form->addElementPrefixPath()`

In your case, you would use - either within the form's `init()` or `__construct()` method - something like:

`$this->addElementPrefixPath('Zend_Form_Element_', APPLICATION_PATH . '/elements);`;

However, I have agree with @Marcin. Naming your own classes with the `Zend_` pseudo-namespace is ill-advised. Either:

1. Decide on an application namespace and declare it in your `Bootstrap` when you create your `$resourceLoader`
2. Create an custom library that resides on your include path - probably at the same level as the Zend library - and put your custom stuff out there.

Let me know if you need more details on either of these suggestions and I'll fatten up the explanations a bit.

**Update based on comments**

Using an empty appnamespace, your call to `addElementPrefixPath()` now changes to:

`$this->addElementPrefixPath('Element_', APPLICATION_PATH . '/elements);`

And I guess you could remove the `elements` entry from the `$resourceLoader` definition in your `Bootstrap` since it's really not doing anything.

**Update 2**

I assumed that you were adding the element to the form using the shortname, something like:

```
$form->addElement('div', 'my_div');
```

In this circumstance, we need to tell the `$form` and its plugin registry where to find an element of type 'div'. That's why we dealt with `$form->addElementPrefixPath()`.

However, from the error message you are reporting, it appears that you are adding your custom element to the form using something like:

```
$div = new Element_Div();
$form->addElement($div, 'my_div');
```

In this case, it is not the `$form` and its plugin registry that has to worry about finding/loading/instantiating the custom element; it is the `$autoloader` via its `$resourceLoader`. In that case, there is no need for the `$form->addElementPrefixPath()`, which is essentially a hint to the form on how to find custom elements invoked by shortname.

What we need is to configure the `$resourceLoader` back in `Bootstrap` so it knows where to find the class. Assuming you stick with empty appnamespace (so your class is named `Element_Div`) and you place the file in `application/forms/elements/Div.php`, then the `$resourceLoader` call is as follows:

```
$resourceLoader->addResourceTypes(array(
    'model' => array(
        'namespace' => 'Model_',
        'path' => 'models'
    ),
    'element' => array(
        'namespace' => 'Element_',
        'path' => 'forms/elements'
    ),
    'form' => array(
        'namespace' => 'Form_',
         'path' => 'forms'
    )
));
```

That should do it. [Famous last words, eh?]

Comment: The only time you should start class names with `Zend_` is for custom view helpers in the default module. For some reason, they still haven't fixed that bug.

Comment: I got confused because of the bug Phil mentioned: My custom element should have been named `Form_Element_Div`, but I was basing my name on my view helpers (because these were in a subdirectory as well). I should have gone with a namespace when I started the project, but I didn't and it's probably a lot of work to change everything now. Still, I'd think it should work now that Zend isn't searching in my library folder anymore, but I'm still getting a similar error (but without invalid path). I'll try addElementPrefixPath(), now that my class doesn't start with 'Zend_', I can do that, right?

Comment: Looks like I can't do that, i tried this in my forms init method: `$this->addElementPrefixPath('Form_Element_', APPLICATION_PATH . '\forms\elements');` and it doesn't work. Still giving me the error: `Fatal error: Class 'Form_Element_Div' not found in C:\xampplite\htdocs\code\application\forms\PostForm.php on line 63`. So David, mind giving some more explanation on the 2nd way you suggested of fixing this? I'll try that.

Comment: @Sled: Given the setup you have, I think you have to name the class `Element_Div`. If that doesn't work, let me know and I'll come up with something else. Good luck, Mr. Phelps. ;-)

Comment: I removed the 'Form_' part, but still getting the same error. Thanks for your help David!

Comment: See "Update based on comments" above.

Comment: My element class is located in `application/forms/elements`. I also tried with your updated code, but still, same result. (removed the code from bootstrap too)

Comment: You have a mismatch among these three factors: the location of the file, the name of the class, and the mapping you are specifying in `addElementPrefixPath()`. From the original `$resourceLoader` definition, I had assumed that file was `application/elements/Div.php`. But if the file is really `application/forms/elements/Div.php`, then your `addElementPrefixPath()` call must be: `$this->addElementPrefixPath('Element_', APPLICATION_PATH . '/forms/elements');` That should do it. Essentially, it's an issue of mapping.

Comment: Alternatively, if you wish to retain the `Form_` prefix for your classname - so that the class is named `Form_Element_Div` and is located in `application/forms/elements/Div.php`, you could use `$this->addElementPrefixPath('Form_Element_', APPLICATION_PATH . '/forms/elements');` But then we get into tricky territory where the autoloader knows how to map things with prefix `Form_` (declared in the resource loader) and the form knows how to add elements with prefix `Form_Element_`, so which one "wins"? It might work fine, but I'd have to test first.

Comment: I wouldn't mind not having Form_ in my prefix, i just want it to work:) I had tried both with and without the 'form' and none of them are working. I have also updated my post, because it's getting messy in the comments. Still no change though

Comment: I assume you are invoking your form element with `$this->addElement('div', 'my_element', $options), right? Otherwise, we are back into configuring the `$resourceLoader`.

Comment: I'm sorry David, I didn't think the way I was invoking my form elements would matter. I was indeed using the method you describe in your second update, and your solution did the trick. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: No sweat, my own fault for not paying closer attention to the specific error message. Anyway, glad it all worked out. Thanks and cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer creating forms like this:

```
$form->addElement(new My_Form_Element_Whatever(array(
    'name' => 'my_element',
    'label' => 'My element',
)));
```

or

```
$form->addElement($whatever = new My_Form_Element_Whatever(array(
    'name' => 'my_element',
    'label' => 'My element',
)));
$whatever->removeDecorator('Errors');
```

when I need to further modify the element.

Comment: I have them in /library/My/Form/Element. I didn't get the whole App_* madness. Good ol' library works like a charm. IMO it improves loading times too, as it can utilitize über-simple autoloader `include $replaceUnderscoreWithSlash . '.php';`